# Why was Sapna still working for Shalini inspite of being a powerful guy's girlfriend/wife?

Tags: plot-explanation, leila

In the Netflix original "Leila", we see that

Sapna, the maid of Shalini, is later a very rich housewife and her husband, Mohan is the "right hand" of Joshi, the ruler of Aryavarta

When Shalini & Sapna meet, she says she was already with Mohan (who was a right hand to Joshi even back then) when she was a maid of Shalini.

**If she was with Mohan when she was a maid, why was she still working for Shalini?**